# open source tool for SQL Queries

Tags: open-source, sql, mysql, sql-server, postgresql

I program in SQL, however I am not someone who comes from IT.
In my new job, we have to choose an **open source tool for doing only queries** (using SQL language), it means we are going to connect to some transactional databases (MS SQL Server - Analysis Services) for doing queries but no for insert or modify that Databases.

For us, the most important things are:

- A stable tool, having **secure connections** above all.
- Easy to use (easy to create connections and
  configurations)
- An if it is possible have a *visual interface
  (workbench for example)* because my colleague does not program (she usually worked in Access using the visual interface for doing her queries)
- Better if it permits to do subqueries.

*Thank you very much for your advice.*

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much any [maintained open-source SQL Editor](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=open%20source%20sql%20editors&t=ffab&ia=web) may be suitable for you.

It really depends if you prefer also to be lightweight:

- [Squirrel SQL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/) - small footprint, universal (both source and os), actively developed java tool. Visual interface is very basic and not intuitive (like in Access).
- [Execute query](http://executequery.org/index.php) - pretty much the same as squirrel, but not that often updated (recently got an update to jre 1.8).
- [Beekeeper](https://www.beekeeperstudio.io/) - It is mature and secure enough (electron-based) and platform independent (you did not specify win/linux/mac) however it is missing visual interface for building queries.

However if you compare what [SQL query programming tools](https://www.beekeeperstudio.io/) offer, you'll find that it covers with topic [Database Management Tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_programming_tool) (in fact you can find all of above mentioned products there). I'd then recommend this open-source database management tool :

- [Dbeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) - my personal favorite, very broad support of drivers (which can be easily updated), actively maintained and easy to use.

There are many more products, these are based on my opinion easy to be learned with intuitive user interface and broad documentation.

Comment: Good choices basically – except that Toad would be quite an overkill (it's great, I often use it myself – but a bit much for "simple queries") and not open-source (one of the OPs requirements, going by the tags). DbVisualizer doesn't seem to be open-source either. Dbeaver indeed seems to be the best of them :)

Comment: Thank you, I am putting Toad and DbVisualizer away, there is free version available but they are not open-source.

Comment: Thanks! I've already upvoted your answer. Nice sum up! Looked short at first glance – but has all the basic points, great!

Answer (score 0):

Because in your question you are tagging `SQL Server`, `MySQL`, `PostgreSQL` and `Open Source`, this makes me think that you are going to deal with a whole bunch of RDBMS.

In this case I would suggest [DbVisualizer](https://www.dbvis.com/) as it can interact with all of them.